# Laravel middleware get route parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I am coding some thing like 'school club manage system' and meet some problem on rights authorization of resource .

Suppose there are `club` , and `club` have manager , and i want to check if the user is a manager of `club` before he can manage it  with a middleware.

Using laravel 5.2

My  `router` looks like that :

`Route::resource('club', 'ClubController');`

The middleware I create looks like that :

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()){
            // ask user to login
        }

        $club = Club::findOrFail($request->input('club'));
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!$club->managers->contains($user)){
            //tell user your are not manager .
        }

        return $next($request);
}
```

But I failed to get the id of club from `requests` .

How can I solve the problem ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

if you are looking for the url parameters the best way of getting that from the resource routes in laravel 5.2 inside the middleware is below. Lets say you want to get id parameter form url club/edit/{id}

```
$request->route()->parameter('id');
```

Comment: From inspecting the source you can pass the parameter name to the route method and it works the same way, `$request->route('id')`

Answer (score 10):

A shorter syntax is:

```
$request->route('parameter_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Woops , I found the ans after checking `dd($requests)`.

I can use `$requests->club` to get parameter .

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Also it would be fair to do an existence check before doing findOrFail whether request has the data using !empty($request->club) or by $request->has('club') to avoid an unnecessary database read.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Laravel 5.5 and

```
dd($request->route()->parameter('id'));
dd($request->route('id'));
```

worked for me