# Laravel 5.5: how get a param from the URL in the middleware and in the controller?

Tags: php, laravel

Solved: global middleware the $request is NULL.

See: [$request->route() is null in Middleware, how can I filter by route parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868759/request-route-is-null-in-middleware-how-can-i-filter-by-route-parameters)

---

Preamble: I'm learning Laravel, from a couple of days.

(I know that this is not secure, but I want only understand better the logic and working), but we presume that we have a API based system.

We have several URL/Controller:

`/{script}/{secret}`, so for example:

`/heater/123456789`

`/ddns/123456789`

`/telegram/123456789`

So, If we call `heater`, we need to:

1 - Check if secret (123456789) is == to another hardcoded in .env (or another place)

2 - Call the right Controller/Service, based on `{script}` params

This is the basic web.php file for Route:

`Route::get('/{script}/{secret}', 'BaseController@getTheScriptFromUrl');`

So, for first point I know better use a `Middleware`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckSecret
{

    /**
     * The secret.
     * TODO: remove from here and move to .env, for example
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $secret = '123456789';

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     * Check if secret in the params is == to saved secret.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ($request->secret == $this->getSecret()) {
            echo 'You can move on!';
        } else {
            echo 'No! You cannot enter!';
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Get the secret
     *
     * @return string the secret
     */
    private function getSecret()
    {
        return $this->secret;
    }
}
```

(I know also I don't need to echo, but return/redirect, it is only a test!).

How can I get the secret inside middleware?

2 - For the second question, I have a `BaseController` to manage the right start for right Controller. But, how can I get access to which script we need?

```
<?php

/**
 * Base Controller that redirect to right controller,
 * based on the URL params.
 *
 * @author sineverba
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    //
    /**
     * Get the param from the URL and redirect to right controller.
     *
     */
    public function getTheScriptFromUrl()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel middleware get route parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762302/laravel-middleware-get-route-parameter)

Comment: if you have a middleware then as per your first question you should be able to get 'secret' (if its in url) with `$request->secret` and if its a valid then simply let the request pass on. else do whatever you wish in else part! then again as per your route file the required controller will be called by laravel and you can still do $request->secret; in controller and perform your task

Comment: I'd make the secret a GET parameter instead of part of the url. Makes more sense from a design perspective.

Comment: dd($request) and see